# theorem; 3-edge-colorability requires a 1-factorization

Tags: graph-theory

My book says the following:

> The Petersen graph is 3-regular; 3-edge-colorability requires a 1-factorization.

I'm not sure why they need a 1-factorization. Is it a theorem that supports the requirement of a 1-factorization in the case of the 3-edge-colorability of a 3-regular graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the edges are colored red white, and blue.  Since every vertex is of degree 3, every vertex is incident on a blue edge. Now no two blue edges have a common vertex, so the blue edges are a one-factor.

Comment: O right. So basically, if a graph has a proper $k$-edge-colouring, you know it has $k$ matchings. Now, we show that for any of the three colours, each vertex is saturated by the associated matching, hence we have a perfect matching (a 1-factor).

Comment: Yes, I think one can look at it like this.